# How to compile play-services:11.2.0

Tags: android, google-maps, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, android-support-library

I want to get current place of my device, and I follow this link:[google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/current-place-tutorial#get-the-location-of-the-android-device-and-position-the-map)
And this tutorial requires Google Play services version 11.2.0 or later.
But when I compile '`com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.0`', I get :

```
Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0
```

here is my build.gradle(Module:app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.administrator.googlemap"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

And here is my build.grandle(Project)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com/"}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

How can I resolve this Error.?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of variable version name

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
```

Use constant version, latest is `26.1.0`

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

You've google maven repo link in buildscript repository list, You should also add google maven repo in project dependencies repository list of your root `build.gradle` file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com/"}
    }
}
```

Selective compile is better option instead of complete `play-services` artifacts, you should choose what you needed in your project.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.0'  // -> latest is 11.4.0
```

break it into your required artifact, like

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.0'
```

**If you're using Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.0 or latter version**

```
repositories {
      mavenLocal()
      mavenCentral()
      google()        //---> Add this
}
```

replace `compile` with `implementation`, More about this replacement [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration)

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
```

in your build.gradle, ie,

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}
```

And also remove other google dependencies if you use play service 11.2.0

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.0'
```